# Satisfying an inequality in an Octave 3D plot

Tags: octave

Suppose I generate a plot in the following way:

```
x=linspace(-2,2,50);
y=linspace(-2,2,50);
[xx,yy]=meshgrid(x,y);
mesh(xx,yy,4-(xx.^2+yy.^2))
```

Is there anyway to impose an inequality such that I only plot values where x < y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly similar to another answer already provided, but might help with the "strange aberration" you mention that answer caused in your data. Basically create a mask that is `1` where `xx < yy`, and `0` otherwise:

```
mask = xx < yy;
```

Then apply this mask to your `xx` and `yy` meshes:

```
xx_mask = xx.*mask;
yy_mask = yy.*mask;
```

And only then do you plot your results:

```
mesh(xx_mask, yy_mask, 4-(xx_mask.^2 + yy_mask.^2));
```

Basically the only difference is that this way you are setting the unwanted values in your `xx` and `yy` matrices to zero before you square them and plot them.

[image]

Note, this was tested with MATLAB instead of Octave, but they should give similar results.

Comment: That fixed things perfectly! Thank you guys for guiding me to the solution! If I had a higher rep I would vote up both of you!

Comment: @Engineero, your answer is exactly mine, except that I missed the mask in the last argument of `mesh` (my bug). You should have fixed mine instead of answering yourself.

Comment: @juliohm you are correct. I started out trying to do things quite differently, with `find` and even tried a bit with `sparse`, but it ended up kind of just converging to your solution. I will delete it, as you certainly had it first. **Edit:** I cannot delete. Hopefully the OP will see this and mark yours instead.

Answer (score 2):

One possible hack:

```
x = y = linspace(-2, 2, 50);
[xx, yy] = meshgrid(x, y);
cond = xx < yy;
xx = xx .* cond;
yy = yy .* cond;
mesh(xx, yy, 4-(xx.^2+yy.^2));
```

Strictly speaking, this will *move* all coordinate pairs `(x,y)` that do not meet the criterion `x < y` from their current location to the origin of the plot:

[image]

Comment: This almost worked in my case, but it caused a strange aberration in the plot I am actually producing. Very close though!

Comment: @mjnichol, it's a trivial bug: I missed the `cond` in the last argument of `mesh`. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions above are only good if the point (0,0) is part of your chart. Otherwise it adds the point to the chart and then tries to plot, creating strange effect, like below.

```
[![x=linspace(1,3,50);
y=linspace(1,3,50);
\[xx,yy\]=meshgrid(x,y);
mask = xx < yy;
xx_mask = xx.*mask;
yy_mask = yy.*mask;
mesh(xx_mask, yy_mask, 4-(xx_mask.^2 + yy_mask.^2));][1]][1]
```

What can be alternatively be done is to leave x and y axes values as is and only convert z axis values to NA inthe range not satisfying the condition.

```
x=linspace(1,3,50);
y=linspace(1,3,50);
[xx,yy]=meshgrid(x,y);
mask = xx < yy;

function result = applyCondition(cond)
  result = ifelse(cond, 0, NA);
endfunction

zz = 4-(xx.^2 + yy.^2);
mesh(xx, yy, zz + arrayfun(@applyCondition, mask));
```

This solution works in all cases, regardless of (0,0) being part of you chart of not.